# Nodejs - HTTP - with optional parameter

Tags: node.js, http, express, parameters

I need to make a http call within my node server .The optional parameter is:

- 'name='

This means that url (relative path) should look like:

```
/v1/clans?name=**exampleValue**
```

So far the options for my http request looks like:

```
app.get('/v1/:clans?=:name', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.path)
    const options = {
        host: 'api.clashofclans.com',
        path: req.path,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: 'Bearer *token*'
        }
    };
    const x = https.get(options, (request) => {...});
```

But that doesnt work out. Does someone know how to include the optional parameters in my path property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't. That's not a parameter you're thinking of. That's a query parameter and your path should look like this:

`'/v1/clans`

You retrieve the query parameter using `req.query.<parameter>` in your case `req.query.name`

The optional url parameter you're thinking of would be like this `/v1/clans/:name` and would be accessible using `req.params.name`.